# POSTing a DateTime from Android to a WCF RESTful JSON Service

Tags: android, wcf, rest, datetime, android-json

I'm trying to send a `DateTime` as a parameter to a method exposed over a WCF RESTful service with JSON encoding. The request looks like this:

```
POST http://IP:PORT/LogService/json/GetLogEntriesByModule HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 100
Content-Type: application/json
Host: IP:PORT
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Expect: 100-Continue

{"maxentries":10,"upperdate":"1280703601462","lowerdate":"1277938801462","module":"Windows Service"}
```

I tried several formats for the `DateTime`:

- `2010-07-01T10:54:00` (which is send by the `WCFTestClient` application over NET.TCP and it gets results
- `\/Date(12345678+0100)\/`
- `01.07.2010 10:54:00`

The method definition:

```
LogEntry[] GetLogEntriesByModule(
    string module,
    DateTime lowerDate,
    DateTime upperDate,
    int maxEntries,
    out bool maxEntriesReached
)
```

I always get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 60
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2010 09:07:04 GMT

{"GetLogEntriesByModuleResult":[],"maxEntriesReached":false}
```

It seems the `DateTime` isn't correctly parsed, because there are several entries in the Llog for that time.

Does anyone know on how to do this?

**Update**: The problem was on the server side and has been resolved.

Comment: What web service are you trying to send the data to? If it's one with public documentation maybe there's some information in there

Comment: Its a ForTheRecord Webservice (http'://4therecord.eu/) and i only got the API Interfaces. I'm in contact with the developer of this program, but I don't know if its a error in the Service or something else.
I haven't found anything on how the DateTime should be passed to the WebService.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct format for posting dates to WCF service is using:
`/Date(53244000000)/`
where the number in brackets is the number of milliseconds since 1970 UTC Midnight.

```
Date dt = new Date();
long date = Date.UTC(dt.getYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDay(), dt.getHours(),dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds());
String senddate = "/date("+date+")/";
```

And then use it as below

```
inputparam.put("DateTime", datetime);
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it is generally true. As I have written, there was also a problem on the server side but that is resolved and using this strange format it works.

Comment: Do you mean: `inputparam.put("DateTime", senddate)`?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this helps somebody:

According to Microsoft, WCF uses a [QueryStringConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.querystringconverter.aspx) to do the url parsing. Thus, using this code (slight modification of the msdn example):

```
QueryStringConverter converter = new QueryStringConverter();
if (converter.CanConvert(typeof(DateTime)))
{
    string strValue = converter.ConvertValueToString(DateTime.UtcNow, typeof(DateTime));
    Console.WriteLine("the value = {0}", strValue);
}
```

we get the proper format for DateTime REST parameters: 2010-01-01T01:01:01Z

I did read that you tried this format, but just wanted to confirm that this is indeed the way it's supposed to work. I thought of answering since this question came up first when I searched for this.

This worked for me using .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have to update the answer to this question, I needed to do the same and I used the accepted answer but the obtained Date was wrong, It was giving me a Date of a week before (Don't know why). I don't know much about the Date type of Java but I know some of their methods has been deprecated.

Being said that I think this is the most recent correct answer for this situation. Hope helps Someone else

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

.....

    final Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));        
    cal.setTime(value); // Where Value is a Date
    final long date = cal.getTime().getTime();
    final String senddate = "/Date("+date+")/";
```

Note the use of Date with the **Uppercase "D"**, this is also needed because it causes problems with the WCF (at least on my case, was stuck a lot just for the lowercase D)

I'm using it to consume a RESTful WCF with Jackson Library for JSON.

To add a complete answer it can be used this Way for a Date that you want to be serialized with jackson.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase;

/**
 * @author HECTOR
 *
 */
public class SerializeRESTDate extends SerializerBase<Date> {

    public SerializeRESTDate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this(Date.class);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    protected SerializeRESTDate(Class<Date> t) {
        super(t);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {


        final Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));            
        cal.setTime(value);
        final long date = cal.getTime().getTime();
        final String senddate = "/Date("+date+")/";
        jgen.writeString(senddate);

    }



}
```

And use it like this in your class'property definition

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SerializeRESTDate.class)
    @JsonProperty("InspectionDate")
    /**
     * @return the _InspectionDate
     */
    public Date get_InspectionDate() {
        return _InspectionDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code I use to send from Android Java to .NET WebApp. Create a JSON object with a date in the W3C XML schema:

```
Calendar myCalendarObj = Calendar.getInstance(); // Snap a moment in time

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(); // Create a JSON object (org.json.JSONObject)

SimpleDateFormat jsonDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); // from java.text.SimpleDateFormat
String senddate = jsonDateFormat.format(myCalendarObj.getTime());
jObj.put("a_date_field", senddate);
```