# Transform Date to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, datetime

I got the following date input Sat May 23 18:09:05 EEST 2015 ,

how can i `convert` it into this format of `json`

```
"PublishedTo":"\/Date(1432645752000+0200)\/"
```

Comment: based on date here your time stamp is wrong +0200 means??

Comment: this is the date format updated Sat May 23 18:09:05 EEST 2015

Comment: base on your date time stamp is 1432404545000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seems like the date/time wire format used in WCF. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it states:

> DateTime values appear as JSON strings in the form of
>   "/Date(700000+0500)/", where the first number (700000 in the example
>   provided) is the number of milliseconds in the GMT time zone, regular
>   (non-daylight savings) time since midnight, January 1, 1970. The
>   number may be negative to represent earlier times. The part that
>   consists of "+0500" in the example is optional and indicates that the
>   time is of the Local kind - that is, should be converted to the local
>   time zone on deserialization. If it is absent, the time is
>   deserialized as Utc. The actual number ("0500" in this example) and
>   its sign (+ or -) are ignored.

If so, this issue has been discussed several times on SO.

[.net JSON Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589816/net-json-date-format)

[POSTing a DateTime from Android to a WCF RESTful JSON Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164480/posting-a-datetime-from-android-to-a-wcf-restful-json-service)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String givenDateString = "5/28/2015"; 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
        long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```